# How to pause an animation in SWIFT?

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I have seen several answers here on stackoverflow but they are all diferent to what I really need, and also they are all in Objective C...
So what I have is an animation of an object called stick that starts up and then goes down to the screen. When I press a button, I want it to pause and I want the stick to be precisely at that spot!
Also, hand is the button that stops the animation, that only stops when hand and stick and overlap.
Here's my code:

```
@IBAction func touchHand(sender: UIButton) {
    let stickPresentationFrame = (stick.layer.presentationLayer() as! CALayer).frame
    if !CGRectIsNull(CGRectIntersection(stickPresentationFrame, hand.frame)){
        println("sup")

    }

}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(2, animations: {self.stick.center = CGPointMake(self.stick.center.x, 760)}, completion: nil)
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this?